# wrong syntax-coloring in fiddler

Tags: xml, fiddler

I use Fiddler to debug POST queries and to view the response.
The service returns a serialized xml so I select the *SyntaxView* tab.

It seems that Fiddler's xml parser gets confused when a tag name contains a hyphen.
I guess it's supposed to print tag names in blue and attribute names in red, but when the tag names contains a hyphen, the part after the hyphen is printed in red.

[image]

To my mind, **capp-table** should all be in blue.

Am I missing something here? I'm pretty sure that the hyphen is allowed in tag names (as long as it's not the first character).

Comment: XML tags can contain hyphens: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp#midcontentadcontainer I would post that question in Telerik forum or send it as bug report to Telerik.

Comment: Syntax highlighting is often done without a completely thorough parsing process, but all the same, this does look rather clumsy.